# Как отсортировать TreeSet по выбранному критерию при помощи интерфейса Comparable<T>?

Tags: java, коллекции, интерфейс

Должно отсортировать по цене, но пишет вроде бы то, что обычно пишет, если Comparable не использовать, если я правильно понял. Повторял за примером с сайта и скорее всего чего-то недопонял, вот ссылка, если понадобится: https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/interfejsy-comparable-comparator-java/

1 файл:

```
public interface Comparable<T>{

    public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

2 файл:

```
public class Guns implements Comparable<Guns>{

    float weight;
    long price;
    String manifacturerName;
    boolean hasOwner;

    public Guns(float weight, long price, String manifacturerName, boolean hasOwner){
        this.weight = weight;
        this.price = price;
        this.manifacturerName = manifacturerName;
        this.hasOwner = hasOwner;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Guns{");
        sb.append("weight=").append(weight);
        sb.append(", price=").append(price);
        sb.append(", manifacturerNname=").append(manifacturerName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", hasOwner=").append(hasOwner);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public int compareTo(Guns anotherGun) {

        if(this.price == anotherGun.price) {
            return 0;

        } else if(this.price > anotherGun.price) {
            return -1;

        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

3 файл:

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class ComparableTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        TreeSet<Guns> gunsTreeSet = new TreeSet<>();

        Guns portalGun = new Guns(4.56f, 243_463_244, "Aperture Science", false);
        Guns gravityGun = new Guns(4.95f, 356_568, "East Black Mesa", true);
        Guns shotGun = new Guns(3.12f, 12_345, "Alliance", true);

        gunsTreeSet.add(portalGun);
        gunsTreeSet.add(gravityGun);
        gunsTreeSet.add(shotGun);

        for(Guns h:gunsTreeSet){
            System.out.println(h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: @zolt В заголовке :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По документации [`Comparable.compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) отрицательное число нужно возвращать когда текущий объект меньше объекта, с которым производится сравнение:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
>
> *Возвращает отрицательное целое, ноль или положительное целое если текущий объект меньше, равен или больше переданного соответственно.*

У вас метод возвращает -1 когда цена текущего оружия больше цены переданного. Соответственно, объекты сортируются по убыванию.

Если хотите сортировать по возрастанию, то измените знак сравнения:

```
} else if(this.price < anotherGun.price) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

P.S. Для корректной сортировки нужно использовать интерфейс из стандартной библиотеки ([`java.lang.Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)) свой интерфейс `Comparable` объявлять не нужно.